# 'and' or 'to' to specify a range

Tags: prepositions

I have the following sentences:

1. Simulations show cost reductions of between 4% **and/to** 15% and
   reductions of between 2% **and/to** 4% regarding the demand.
2. The method leads to improvements of between 15% **and/to** 54%

I always want to specify a range. Would you rather use 'and' or 'to' in these 3 examples?

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Do the [examples in a dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/between) help? "A man aged between 18 and 30" uses *and* and is the same construction as your sentence.

Comment: Between A and B; not A to B.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Andrew and Ram.

Comment: It's _from A to B_ and _between A and B_. The _from...to_ and _between ...and_ frames are important.